# How can use resize image with this code?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, backend

how can use following code with resize feature?

```
if ($_item->getProductType() == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE && count($_item->getChildrenItems()) > 0) {
    $_productThumbnail = $_item->getChildrenItems()[0]->getProduct()->getThumbnail();
}
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')  
                                ->getMediaUrl($_productThumbnail ); ?>" width="150" height="150" alt="" style="float:left;margin-right:10px" />
```